# R tables with ggplot style facets

Tags: r, r-markdown

Say you have data with 3 categories, 2 subcategories and some summary statistics. Is there a way to succinctly produce 3 separate tables?

```
library(pander)
df<-data.frame(planet=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
               ,continent=c('A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B')
               ,statistic1 = sample(12)
               ,statistic2= sample(12))

pandoc.table(df[df$planet==1,])
pandoc.table(df[df$planet==2,])
pandoc.table(df[df$planet==3,])
```

I was hoping there would be a library that allows creating tables with a ggplot `facet_grid` like syntax

```
pandoc.table(df)+facet_grid(planet ~ .)
```

Comment: you could use a `for` loop but you can use other split-apply functions: `o =  by(df, list(df$planet, df$continent), FUN=pandoc.table) ` or `dt = as.data.table(df) ; o = dt[, pandoc.table(data.frame(.BY, .SD)), by=planet:continent]`

Answer (score 0):

You could consider writing a function yourself.  E.g.:

```
a <- y ~ .
all.vars(a)
[1] "y" "."
```